# headless OSGi framework from command line

Tags: osgi, equinox

At the moment I am invoking the equinox OSGi system using:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console
```

Framework shutdowns immediately when I can exit from it which is normal.
However, I want to keep the Framework run indefinitely. 
What can be the best way for doing so? and I know I can start equinox framework programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use "java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console -Dosgi.noShutdown=true".

Not sure if it works with your version but I works with 3.7.2 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the framework has something thing to do ... the framework only exists when there is no non-daemon thread running. If all your bundles are just waiting for callbacks ... noting can ever happen. So you need at least one bundle that is waiting on the UI thread, a web server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html) to run a Java application as a Windows/Linux service